# Running 2 apps simultaneously on Spring Tool Suite 4

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two projects in the same workspace that need to run at the same time. I just switched to using Spring Tool Suite 4. I used to do this by having two instances of Eclipse open. I want to run one using Boot (the embedded server) and the other on Tomcat 9. I did try it and both appeared to be running but the console output seems to track only one of the apps. Am I setting up the apps the wrong way? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this -

- located near your console tab should be a button "Open Console".
- If you click this button one of your options should be "New Console
  View".

[Eclipse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O8vB.jpg)

You'll now have 2 console views.

One of your other buttons near your console tab is "Display Selected Console". When you choose this option you can select from any of your running applications.

Just select the tab, select which application you want it to watch, and repeat for the other tab.

You can then move your 2 console views to wherever you want independently of each other.

Comment: Is there a way to open one console for each application automatically? I mean, when I start, it opens separated console over and over?